# JSSOR - Loop through all slides and images in nested slider No-Jquery

Tags: slider, nested, jssor

Ive seen the the response for the question on how to loop through all the slides, but the answer given is for the Jquery version. How would I get it to work with the No Jquery version? I dont seem to be able to alter the code to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same.

The only difference is the way to initialize jssor slider.

Please see

[Basic Usage (jQuery)](http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html)

[Basic Usage(No-jQuery)](http://www.jssor.com/development/basic-usage-no-jquery.html)

Comment: Thanks, For some reason just copying the code from the previouys answer didnt work. I ended up copying the source from the page linked to in the previous answer and now it seems to work OK